# What is a short cut I can use to switch applications?

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

In Mac OS it was command+tab. It is one of the most helpful tools, and I was wondering what was it's Ubuntu equivalent?

Comment: Tip: Press the Super (aka "Windows") key 3 seconds to see the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used to easily switch between windows in Unity and most other Desktops - holding  <kbd>Alt</kbd> down and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly can be used to quickly switch between windows.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the second key is just above <kbd>Tab</kbd> on a few keyboards) can be used to switch between windows of the same application

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NUMBER</kbd> can be used to select items from the launcher, 
 whilst <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should switch between applications in the launcher.

Other short cuts are shown on first login (in 14.04 atleast) or by holding down <kbd>Super</kbd>:
[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about the ability to switch between two windows of the same application. That's a new level :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Unity 3d it's "magic-key" + w.  In Unity 2d it's alt + tab.

Comment: alt+tab works in 3d as well ;)

Comment: Super[1] w might also be an option, maybe?   [1] The left windows key - on such a keyboard.